# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nativeElement'): How do I resolve this?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, viewchild, elementref

The state of my current code is like this:

```
<mat-tree-node>
...
 <div *ngIf="node.type=='assembly' || node.type=='part'" style="display: inline;"
                    (contextmenu)="asmStateServ.contextMenu($event, node.name)">{{node.instanceName}}
                    ({{node.name}})
                    <div class="customContext" (click)="asmStateServ.stopPropagation($event)" #menu>
                        <ul>
                            <li (click)="asmStateServ.selectNode(node.name)">Select</li>
                            <li (click)="asmStateServ.deSelectNode(node.name)">Deselect</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
</mat-tree-node>
```

In the .ts file, it is this:

```
@ViewChild('menu') menu: ElementRef
    public contextMenu(event: MouseEvent, node: asmTreeNode | asmTreeNodeFlat | asmTreeNodeScene) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.menu.nativeElement.style.display = "block";
        this.menu.nativeElement.style.top = event.pageY + "px"
        this.menu.nativeElement.style.left = event.pageX + "px"

    }

    public disappearContextMenu() {
        this.menu.nativeElement.style.display = "none";

    }

    public stopPropagation(event: any) {
        event.stopPropagation();

    }
```

However, the menu doesn't open and that specific console error stays on. I was wondering what might be wrong in this case? I am very new in Angular and programming in general so it would mean a lot to me if you write the correct code down :)

Comment: which version your Angular is?

Comment: My version of Angular is 12.0.5

Comment: Your `menu` element isn't initialized for some reason. Maybe the respective element could not be found or it hasn't been loaded yet, or can't event load due to some `*ngIf` restriction. Is your `node.type` the correct one, ie `*ngIf="node.type=='assembly' || node.type=='part'"`?

Comment: Yeah. It is the correct one and it's working perfectly without the menu part.

Comment: from version 9 the default value for `static` is `false` but please check if `@ViewChild('menu', { static: false })` works for you. the problem is because that `*ngIf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're attempting to use `@ViewChild` in the property `asmStateServ`, which I'm guessing by the name is an injected service. `@ViewChild('menu')` only works in the property initializers of the component class, not inside of an injected service. You can easily pass this element as a parameter to these methods though. Note this passes an `HTMLDivElement` not an `ElementRef`.

I'm just showing the relevant parts here.

```html
<mat-tree-node>
  ...
  <div (contextmenu)="asmStateServ.contextMenu($event, menu)">
    ...
    <div #menu>...</div>
  </div>
</mat-tree-node>
```

```js
    public contextMenu(event: MouseEvent, menu: HTMLDivElement) {
        event.preventDefault();
        menu.style.display = "block";
        menu.style.top = event.pageY + "px"
        menu.style.left = event.pageX + "px"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You were completely right. It totally worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can add null checking(?) before your nativeElement

```
        this.menu?.nativeElement?.style.display = "none";
```

Comment: That'll hide the error, but why is menu ever null ? It is called on user event, so the @ViewChild should be correctly initialized. Something else must be wrong with the code...